# navigatorState is null when using pushNamed Navigation onGenerateRoutes of GetMaterialPage

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, agora.io, android-push-notification

I'm using [flutter_callkit_incoming](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming) package to get callsNotification in my application through the payload of FCM in all states of my App i.e background/forground/terminated state.

Navigation is fine now to the VideoCallingAgoraPage after clicking Accept button on call incoming notification on forground state of my app. *-> Using listenerEvent from NikahMatch class*

***But problem comes when this listenerEvent is used for navigation in background/terminated state.*** *-> Using listenerEvent as top level function because of background handler as shown below in my background handler function*

When the compiler reads this line `await NavigationService.instance.pushNamed(AppRoute.voiceCall);` in listener event on clicking accept of notification from flutter_callKit_incoming in the background/terminated state of my app, I am getting this error in console.

```
E/flutter (11545): Receiver: null
E/flutter (11545): Tried calling: pushNamed<Object>("/videoCall_agora", arguments: null)
E/flutter (11545): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:38:5)
E/flutter (11545): #1      NavigationService.pushNamed (package:nikah_match/helpers/navigationService.dart:38:39)
E/flutter (11545): #2      listenerEvent.<anonymous closure> (package:nikah_match/main.dart:311:46)
E/flutter (11545): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11545):
```

As well as in the logs, I find that `log(navigationKey.currentState.toString());` defined in pushNamed function is also `null`. While in the case of forground navigation, navigationKey.currentState from pushNamed function is never null.

**When I received call notification in terminated state, accept case of listener event(top level function) was called without creating widget tree and initializing GetMaterialPage that caused navigator state to be null.**

**I think that the listnerEvent Accept case is run before starting/building widget tree and navigator key in GetMaterialPage is never assigned.**

**How can I get rid of that?**

This is my backgroundHandler function:

```
Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  bool videoCallEnabled = false;
  bool audioCallEnabled = false;

  if (message != null) {
    debugPrint("Handling background is called");
    print(
        "Handling a background message and background handler: ${message.messageId}");
    try {
      videoCallEnabled = message.data.containsKey('videoCall');
      audioCallEnabled = message.data.containsKey('voiceCall');

      if (videoCallEnabled || audioCallEnabled) {
        log("Video call is configured and is started");
        showCallkitIncoming(Uuid().v4(), message: message);
        //w8 for streaming
        debugPrint("Should listen to events in background/terminated state");
        listenerEvent(message);
      } else {
        log("No Video or audio call was initialized");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Error occured:" + e.toString());
    }
  }

}
```

This is my listener event:

```
 Future<void> listenerEvent(RemoteMessage message) async {


  log("Listner event background/terminated handler app has run");
  backgroundChatRoomId = message.data['chatRoomId'];
  backgroundCallsDocId = message.data['callsDocId'];
  backgroundRequesterName = message.data['callerName'];
  backgroundRequesterImageUrl = message.data['imageUrl'];
  // String imageUrl = message.data['imageUrl'];

  bool videoCallEnabled = false;


  if (message.data != null) {
    videoCallEnabled = message.data.containsKey('videoCall');
  } else {
    log("Data was null");
  }
  try {
    FlutterCallkitIncoming.onEvent.listen((event) async {
      print('HOME: $event');
      switch (event.name) {
        case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_INCOMING:
        // TODO: received an incoming call
          log("Call is incoming");
          break;
        case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_START:
        // TODO: started an outgoing call
        // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
          log("Call is started");
          break;
        case CallEvent.ACTION_CALL_ACCEPT:
        // TODO: accepted an incoming call
        // TODO: show screen calling in Flutter
          log("......Call Accepted background/terminated state....");
          currentChannel = backgroundChatRoomId;
          log("currentChannel in accepted is: $currentChannel");
          debugPrint("Details of call"+backgroundChatRoomId+backgroundCallsDocId );
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("ChatRoom")
              .doc(backgroundChatRoomId)
              .collection("calls")
              .doc(backgroundCallsDocId)
              .update({
            'receiverCallResponse': 'Accepted',
            'callResponseDateTime': FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          }).then((value) => log("Values updated at firebase firestore as Accepted"));

          if (videoCallEnabled) {
            log("in video call enabled in accept call of listener event");
            await NavigationService.instance.pushNamed(AppRoute.videoAgoraCall,);
           
          } 
          break;

      }
    });
  } on Exception {}
}
```

This is my first stateful GetMaterial page which initializes all Firebase Messaging functions (Forground Local FLutter local notifications excluded from code for readability):

```
class NikkahMatch extends StatefulWidget {
  const NikkahMatch({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NikkahMatch> createState() => _NikkahMatchState();
}

class _NikkahMatchState extends State<NikkahMatch> with WidgetsBindingObserver {


  


    @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
//Function if from terminated state
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) async {

      log("get Initial Message function is used.. ");

      String screenName = 'No screen';
      bool screenEnabled = false;
      if (message != null) {
        if (message.data != null) {
          log("Remote message data is null for now");
          if (message.data.isNotEmpty) {
            screenEnabled = message.data.containsKey('screenName');
            if (screenEnabled) {
              if (screenName == 'chatScreen') {
                log("Screen is Chat");
                String type = 'Nothing';
                String chatRoomId = 'Nothing';
                if (message.data['type'] != null) {
                  type = message.data['type'];
                  if (type == 'profileMatched') {
                    String likerId = message.data['likerId'];
                    String likedId = message.data['likedId'];
                    chatRoomId = chatController.getChatRoomId(likerId, likedId);
                  }
                } else {
                  chatRoomId = message.data['chatRoomId'];
                }

                log("ChatRoom Id is: ${chatRoomId}");
                log("Navigating from onMessagePop to the ChatRoom 1");
                //We have chatRoomId here and we need to navigate to the ChatRoomScreen having same Id
                await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("ChatRoom")
                    .doc(chatRoomId)
                    .get()
                    .then((value) async {
                  if (value.exists) {
                    log("ChatRoom Doc " + value.toString());
                    log("Navigating from onMessagePop to the ChatRoom 2");
                    log("Last Message was : ${value.data()['lastMessage']}");
                    backGroundLevelChatRoomDoc = value.data();
                   
                    await NavigationService.instance.pushNamed(AppRoute.chatScreen);
                  } else {
                    log("no doc exist for chat");
                  }
                });
              }

          else if (screenName == 'videoScreen') {
                log("Screen is Video");
                initCall(message);
              } else if (screenName == 'voiceScreen') {
                log("Screen is Audio");
                initCall(message);
              } else {
                log("Screen is in Else method of getInitialMessage");
              }
            
            } else {
              debugPrint("Notification Pay load data is Empty");
            }
          } else {
            log("Screen isn't enabled");
          }
        } else {
          log("message data is null");
        }
      } else {
        log("...........message data is null in bahir wala else");
      }
    });

   
    //This function will constantly listen to the notification recieved from firebase

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      log("onMessageOpenedApp function is used.. ");
      String screenName = 'No screen';
      bool screenEnabled = false;
      if (message.data.isNotEmpty) {
        screenEnabled = message.data.containsKey('screenName');
        if (screenEnabled) {
          //Move to the screen which is needed to
          log("Screen is Enabled");
          screenName = message.data['screenName'];
          log("Screen name is: $screenName");

          if (screenName == 'chatScreen') {
            log("Screen is Chat");
            String type = 'Nothing';
            String chatRoomId = 'Nothing';
            if (message.data['type'] != null) {
              type = message.data['type'];
              if (type == 'profileMatched') {
                String likerId = message.data['likerId'];
                String likedId = message.data['likedId'];
                chatRoomId = chatController.getChatRoomId(likerId, likedId);
              }
            } else {
              chatRoomId = message.data['chatRoomId'];
            }

            log("ChatRoom Id is: ${chatRoomId}");
            log("Navigating from onMessagePop to the ChatRoom 1");
            //We have chatRoomId here and we need to navigate to the ChatRoomScreen having same Id
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("ChatRoom")
                .doc(chatRoomId)
                .get()
                .then((value) async {
              if (value.exists) {
                log("ChatRoom Doc " + value.toString());
                log("Navigating from onMessagePop to the ChatRoom 2");
                log("Last Message was : ${value.data()['lastMessage']}");
                backGroundLevelChatRoomDoc = value.data();
                /*     await NavigationService.instance
                    .pushNamed(AppRoute.chatScreen, args:ChatArgs(value.data(), false));*/
                await NavigationService.instance.pushNamed(AppRoute.chatScreen);
              } else {
                log("no doc exist for chat");
              }
            });
          }

       else if (screenName == 'videoScreen') {
            log("Screen is Video");
            initCall(message);
          } else if (screenName == 'voiceScreen') {
            log("Screen is Audio");
            initCall(message);
          } else {
            log("Screen is in Else");
          }
        }
      } else {
        debugPrint("Notification Pay load data is Empty");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Main page build");
    return GetMaterialApp(
      onGenerateRoute: AppRoute.generateRoute,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: NavigationService.instance.navigationKey,
      debugShowMaterialGrid: false,
      title: 'Nikah Match',
      initialRoute: '/splash_screen',
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: kScaffoldBgColor,
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
        ),
        accentColor: kPrimaryColor.withOpacity(0.2),
      ),
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      getPages: [
        GetPage(name: '/splash_screen', page: () => SplashScreen()),
        GetPage(name: '/get_started', page: () => GetStarted()),
        GetPage(
          name: '/videoCall_agora',
          page: () => VideoCallAgoraUIKit(
            anotherUserName: backgroundRequesterName,
            anotherUserImage: backgroundRequesterImageUrl,
            channelName: backgroundChatRoomId,
            token: "",
            anotherUserId: "",
            docId: backgroundCallsDocId,
            callDoc: backgroundPassableAbleCdm,
          ),
        ),
        // GetPage(name: '/after_log_in_screen', page: () => AfterLogin()),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my NavigationService class:

```
class NavigationService {
  // Global navigation key for whole application
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigationKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  /// Get app context
  BuildContext get appContext => navigationKey.currentContext;

  /// App route observer
  RouteObserver<Route<dynamic>> routeObserver = RouteObserver<Route<dynamic>>();

  static final NavigationService _instance = NavigationService._private();
  factory NavigationService() {
    return _instance;
  }
  NavigationService._private();

  static NavigationService get instance => _instance;

  /// Pushing new page into navigation stack
  ///
  /// `routeName` is page's route name defined in [AppRoute]
  /// `args` is optional data to be sent to new page
  Future<T> pushNamed<T extends Object>(String routeName,
      {Object args}) async {
    log(navigationKey.toString());
    log(navigationKey.currentState.toString());
    return navigationKey.currentState.pushNamed<T>(
      routeName,
      arguments: args,
    );
  }

  Future<T> pushNamedIfNotCurrent<T extends Object>(String routeName,
      {Object args}) async {
    if (!isCurrent(routeName)) {
      return pushNamed(routeName, args: args);
    }
    return null;
  }

  bool isCurrent(String routeName) {
    bool isCurrent = false;
    navigationKey.currentState.popUntil((route) {
      if (route.settings.name == routeName) {
        isCurrent = true;
      }
      return true;
    });
    return isCurrent;
  }

  /// Pushing new page into navigation stack
  ///
  /// `route` is route generator
  Future<T> push<T extends Object>(Route<T> route) async {
    return navigationKey.currentState.push<T>(route);
  }

  /// Replace the current route of the navigator by pushing the given route and
  /// then disposing the previous route once the new route has finished
  /// animating in.
  Future<T> pushReplacementNamed<T extends Object, TO extends Object>(
      String routeName,
      {Object args}) async {
    return navigationKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed<T, TO>(
      routeName,
      arguments: args,
    );
  }

  /// Push the route with the given name onto the navigator, and then remove all
  /// the previous routes until the `predicate` returns true.
  Future<T> pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<T extends Object>(
      String routeName, {
        Object args,
        bool Function(Route<dynamic>) predicate,
      }) async {
    return navigationKey.currentState.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil<T>(
      routeName,
      predicate==null?  (_) => false: (_) => true,
      arguments: args,
    );
  }

  /// Push the given route onto the navigator, and then remove all the previous
  /// routes until the `predicate` returns true.
  Future<T> pushAndRemoveUntil<T extends Object>(
      Route<T> route, {
        bool Function(Route<dynamic>) predicate,
      }) async {
    return navigationKey.currentState.pushAndRemoveUntil<T>(
      route,
      predicate==null?  (_) => false: (_) => true,
    );
  }

  /// Consults the current route's [Route.willPop] method, and acts accordingly,
  /// potentially popping the route as a result; returns whether the pop request
  /// should be considered handled.
  Future<bool> maybePop<T extends Object>([Object args]) async {
    return navigationKey.currentState.maybePop<T>(args as T);
  }

  /// Whether the navigator can be popped.
  bool canPop() => navigationKey.currentState.canPop();

  /// Pop the top-most route off the navigator.
  void goBack<T extends Object>({T result}) {
    navigationKey.currentState.pop<T>(result);
  }

  /// Calls [pop] repeatedly until the predicate returns true.
  void popUntil(String route) {
    navigationKey.currentState.popUntil(ModalRoute.withName(route));
  }
}
class AppRoute {
  static const homePage = '/home_page';

  static const chatScreen ='/chat_screen';

  static const splash = '/splash_screen';
  static const voiceCall = '/voice_call';
  static const videoAgoraCall = '/videoCall_agora';

  static Route<Object> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case homePage:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => HomePage(), settings: settings);
      case chatScreen:

        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>
                ChatScreen(docs: backGroundLevelChatRoomDoc, isArchived: false,), settings: settings);
        case splash:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>  SplashScreen(), settings: settings);
      case voiceCall:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>  VoiceCall(
              toCallName: backgroundRequesterName,
              toCallImageUrl: backgroundRequesterImageUrl,
              channelName: backgroundChatRoomId,
              token: voiceCallToken,
              docId: backgroundCallsDocId,
              callDoc: backgroundPassableAbleCdm,
            ), settings: settings);
      case videoAgoraCall:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) =>  VideoCallAgoraUIKit(
              anotherUserName: backgroundRequesterName,
              anotherUserImage: backgroundRequesterImageUrl,
              channelName: backgroundChatRoomId,
              token: "",
              anotherUserId: "",
              docId: backgroundCallsDocId,
              callDoc: backgroundPassableAbleCdm,
            ), settings: settings);

      default:
        return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I was also stuck when using [flutter_incoming_callkit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming)  for navigation in terminated/background state for weeks, and strikingly, the solution was so simple.

**The reason causing you this problem is:**

-> For receiving notification in terminated or background state, **backgroundHandler function is working in its own isolate** and onGenerateRoutes from your NikkahMatch class is not and never known to this isolated function where you are actually trying to navigate through the pushNamed route.

**So my solution was:**

-> Use the combination of firestore and cloud functions for navigation. This would allow us to have the context and it won't be null as we are navigating from inside the app widget tree and **not from an isolated function i.e backgroundHandler.** Top-level listenerEvent Function is only used to change the values in the call document on Firestore.

*[Note: Top-Level function is a function that is not part of any class]*

Upon receiving flutter_incoming_callkit notification on receiver side:

On the click of Accept button, use top-level listenerEvent function to change the call status from incoming to accepted in call's document.
This will open the app from terminated/background state.

I used this function `didChangeAppLifecycleState` in my first class of widget tree to handle/know if app has come from terminated/background state:
Check out this code:

```
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    print(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      //Check call when open app from background
      print("in app life cycle resumed");
      checkAndNavigationCallingPage();
    }
  }

checkAndNavigationCallingPage() async {
    print("checkAndNavigationCallingPage CheckCalling page 1");
    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
      print("auth.currentUser.uid: ${auth.currentUser.uid}");
    }

    // NavigationService().navigationKey.currentState.pushNamed(AppRoute.videoAgoraCall);

    var currentCall = await getCurrentCall();
    print("inside the checkAndNavigationCallingPage and $currentCall");

    if (currentCall != null) {
      print("inside the currentCall != null");
      //Here we have to move to calling page
      final g = Get;
      if (!g.isDialogOpen) {
        g.defaultDialog(content: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50));
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Users')
          .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
          .collection('calls')
          .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
          .get()
          .then((userCallDoc) async {
        if (userCallDoc.exists) {
          if (userCallDoc['type'] == 'chapVoiceCall' ||
              userCallDoc['type'] == 'chapVideoCall') {
            bool isDeclined = false;
            String chapCallDocId = "";
            chapCallDocId = userCallDoc['chapCallDocId'];
            print(
                "............. Call was Accepted by receiver or sender.............");
            print("ChapCallDocId $chapCallDocId");
            ChapCallDocModel cdm = ChapCallDocModel();
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("ChatRoom")
                .doc(userCallDoc['chatRoomId'])
                .collection("chapCalls")
                .doc(chapCallDocId)
                .get()
                .then((value) {
              if ((value['requestedResponse'] == 'Declined' &&
                      value['requesterResponse'] == 'Declined') ||
                  (value['senderResponse'] == 'Declined') ||
                  (value['requestedResponse'] == 'TimeOut' &&
                      value['requesterResponse'] == 'TimeOut')) {
                isDeclined = true;
                print(
                    "in checking declined ${value['receiverCallResponse'] == 'Declined' || value['senderCallResponse'] == 'Declined'}");
              } else {
                isDeclined = false;
                cdm = ChapCallDocModel.fromJson(value.data());
                print("CDM print is: ${cdm.toJson()}");
              }
            });
            currentChannel = userCallDoc['chatRoomId'];

            if (!isDeclined) {
              if (userCallDoc['type'] == 'chapVoiceCall') {
                print("in voice call enabled in accept call of listener event");
                var voiceCallToken = await GetToken().getTokenMethod(
                    userCallDoc['chatRoomId'], auth.currentUser.uid);
                print("token before if in splashscreen is: ${voiceCallToken}");
                if (voiceCallToken != null) {
                  if (g.isDialogOpen) {
                    g.back();
                  }
                  Get.to(
                    () => ChapVoiceCall(
                      toCallName: userCallDoc['requesterName'],
                      toCallImageUrl: userCallDoc['requesterImage'],
                      channelName: userCallDoc['chatRoomId'],
                      token: voiceCallToken,
                      docId: userCallDoc['chapCallDocId'],
                      callDoc: cdm,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  print(
                      "......Call Accepted background/terminated state....in token being null in voice call enabled in accept call of listener event");
                }
              } else {
                if (g.isDialogOpen) {
                  g.back();
                }
                g.to(() => ChapVideoCallAgoraUIKit(
                      anotherUserName: userCallDoc['requesterName'],
                      anotherUserImage: userCallDoc['requesterImage'],
                      channelName: userCallDoc['chatRoomId'],
                      token: "",
                      anotherUserId: userCallDoc['requesterId'],
                      docId: userCallDoc['chapCallDocId'],
                      callDoc: cdm,
                    ));
              }
            } else {
              await FlutterCallkitIncoming.endAllCalls();
              print(
                  "the call was either declined by sender or receiver or was timed out.");
            }
          } else {
            bool isDeclined = false;
            print(
                "............. Call was Accepted by receiver or sender.............");
            CallDocModel cdm = CallDocModel();
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection("ChatRoom")
                .doc(userCallDoc['chatRoomId'])
                .collection("calls")
                .doc(userCallDoc['callsDocId'])
                .get()
                .then((value) {
              if (value['receiverCallResponse'] == 'Declined' ||
                  value['senderCallResponse'] == 'Declined' ||
                  value['receiverCallResponse'] == 'TimeOut' ||
                  value['senderCallResponse'] == 'TimeOut') {
                isDeclined = true;
                print(
                    "in checking declined ${value['receiverCallResponse'] == 'Declined' || value['senderCallResponse'] == 'Declined'}");
              } else {
                isDeclined = false;
                cdm = CallDocModel.fromJson(value.data());
                print("CDM print is: ${cdm.toJson()}");
              }
            });
            currentChannel = userCallDoc['chatRoomId'];

            if (!isDeclined) {
              if (userCallDoc['type'] == 'voiceCall') {
                print("in voice call enabled in accept call of listener event");
                var voiceCallToken = await GetToken().getTokenMethod(
                    userCallDoc['chatRoomId'], auth.currentUser.uid);
                print("token before if in splashscreen is: ${voiceCallToken}");
                if (voiceCallToken != null) {
                  if (g.isDialogOpen) {
                    g.back();
                  }
                  Get.to(
                    () => VoiceCall(
                      toCallName: userCallDoc['requesterName'],
                      toCallImageUrl: userCallDoc['requesterImage'],
                      channelName: userCallDoc['chatRoomId'],
                      token: voiceCallToken,
                      docId: userCallDoc['callsDocId'],
                      callDoc: cdm,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  print(
                      "......Call Accepted background/terminated state....in token being null in voice call enabled in accept call of listener event");
                }
              } else {
                if (g.isDialogOpen) {
                  g.back();
                }
                g.to(() => VideoCallAgoraUIKit(
                      anotherUserName: userCallDoc['requesterName'],
                      anotherUserImage: userCallDoc['requesterImage'],
                      channelName: userCallDoc['chatRoomId'],
                      token: "",
                      anotherUserId: userCallDoc['requesterId'],
                      docId: userCallDoc['callsDocId'],
                      callDoc: cdm,
                    ));
              }
            } else {
              await FlutterCallkitIncoming.endAllCalls();
              print(
                  "the call was either declined by sender or receiver or was timed out.");
            }
          }
        } else {
          debugPrint("Document not found");
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

In the above code, I have given my db scenario, so anyone, who needs to know how to handle the different call status can deeply look into it. Or **you can comment here and I would be honored to reply.**